# RootViewController not loading in NIB

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I'm trying to follow the Features Example for the Inferis/ViewDeck library [here](https://github.com/Inferis/ViewDeck). However the Root View Controller is loading but not passing to my Login View. I am using the Login View in place of the View Deck Choices View.

APAppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class LoginController;

@interface APAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

APAppDelegate.m

```
#import "APAppDelegate.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation APAppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    RootViewController *rootController = (RootViewController *)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"RootViewController"];
    self.window.rootViewController = rootController;//[[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

I had to use the MainStoryboard for mine because I am using a storyboard and he uses xib. By trying to initwithNibName in the appdelegate I was getting an error saying the RootViewController didn't exist.

RootViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController
{

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIView *loginView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UINavigationController *navController;

@end
```

RootViewController.m

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "IIViewDeckController.h"
#import "LoginController.h"
#import "SideMenuView.h"
#import "APCustomerViewController.h"

@implementation RootViewController
@synthesize loginView = _loginView;
@synthesize navController = _navController;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"RootViewController viewDidLoad");
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    LoginController *loginController = [[LoginController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginController" bundle:nil];

    self.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginController];
    self.navController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];

    self.navController.view.frame = self.loginView.bounds;
    [self.loginView addSubview:self.navController.view];
    NSLog(@"End RootViewController viewDidLoad");
}
```

LoginController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class KeychainItemWrapper;
@class DataClass;

@interface LoginController : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *userField;
    IBOutlet UITextField *passwordField;
    IBOutlet UISwitch *saveLogin;
    UIActivityIndicatorView *activitySpinner;
    KeychainItemWrapper *keychain;
    DataClass *dataObj;

    id delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *userField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *saveLogin;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id delegate;

@end
```

LoginController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"LoginController viewDidLoad");
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [userField setDelegate:self];
    [passwordField setDelegate:self];
    TextFieldDelegate *myDelegate = [[TextFieldDelegate alloc] init];
    [self setDelegate:myDelegate];
    //set the delegate's currentViewController property so that we can add a subview to this View. 


    activitySpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activitySpinner.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 40.0, 40.0);
    activitySpinner.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:activitySpinner];

    keychain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"APLogin" accessGroup:nil];
    [userField setText:[keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount]];
    [passwordField setText:[keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData]];

    if ([userField text] != @"" && [passwordField text] != @"") {
        [saveLogin setOn:YES];
    }

    dataObj = [DataClass getInstance];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

Log File

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Thu Nov  3 21:59:02 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 18487.
2012-01-20 11:56:11.586 Appointment-Plus[18487:f803] RootViewController viewDidLoad
2012-01-20 11:56:11.589 Appointment-Plus[18487:f803] End RootViewController viewDidLoad
```

I have all my class names in the storyboard nibs the same as the class files. As you can see the RootViewController viewDidLoad is running completely but the LoginController is not running at all. I'm trying to get the LoginController to run from the RootViewController.

My ultimate goal is to get the facebook style menu that slides out but only on some pages. The pages that will use the menu are after the LoginController.

1.) User opens app and gets the login page
2.) User logs in and gets the main page with the facebook ios style menu
3.) When a user clicks an item it can go to a new page that will not have the side menu.

From what I understand a RootViewController is needed in order to manage all this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided not to use the library and just used a root view controller and created my own slide menu.